# Putting a back button inside of a Modal view pushed by another modal view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modalviewcontroller

Check this, im pushing a modal view inside of another modal view. But, im trying to put a button inside of this modal view, but without luck.

What im doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
 CadastroViewController *addController = [[CadastroViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CadastroViewController" bundle:nil];

// This is where you wrap the view up nicely in a navigation controller
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addController];

// You can even set the style of stuff before you show it
navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;

navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buy)];


// And now you want to present the view in a modal fashion all nice and animated
[self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

// make sure you release your stuff
[navigationController release];
[addController release];
```

Comment: Please share your answer with the rest of us.

Comment: @Lucas: Since you don't write the correct answer, I will. Read the forum guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that the problem is here:

```
  [self presentModalViewController: navigationController animated:YES];
```

Instead try do this:

```
  [self presentModalViewController: addController animated:YES];
```

Comment: This wasent the answer AT all. @Max: You are not pushing the navigation controller, but the actual viewcontroller, which is already in focus since it's the top level viewcontroller of the navigation controller. It will give you an error.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to add a new UINavigationItem to the navigationbar of the actual viewcontroller - NOT the navigation controller.

```
addController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buy)];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add your button in a
 `-(void) viewDidLoad` of your `CadastroViewController` controller class

This will look like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(buy)];
    self.navigationController. leftBarButtonItem = button;
    [button release];
}
```

`[self presentModalViewController: navigationController animated:YES];` is ok in your example, just all other initializations you should do in viewDidLoad